# C# form pass values to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# Winforms. There are tons of people asking this question, but I still can't find the answer.

I have a form that manipulates data and uploads the information to a server. Right now I hardcoded the server information. I created another form that asks the user to input the server/login information. I want to pass the server/login information to the first form. How would I go about doing that?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried , show some code and someone may be able to get you going in the right direction.

Comment: You can set your username/password variables as public and when you show the form, use ShowDialog and check for DialogResult.OK. Inside that check you can reference the variables, like: loginForm.Username etc :)

Comment: Which form calls which? (Does the main form pop up another dialog that asks for the information, or does the request form open the processing form after the details have been entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following MSDN page on passing parameters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx

Personally, I would do data access in a separate class and implement a `public void Login(string user, string password, string server)` method. The second form would then make use of this class's other methods to retrieve and display data.

Comment: just to clarify on your suggestion to implement a public void login function... Would you create the function in the first form? and have the second form access it by calling the login function.. how would i go about doing this.. lets say for instance

Comment: sorry.. i had to go to work.. i will consider this option

Comment: Do not put your data access code in either form. Create a third class, `AuthSystem`, which holds a public `bool Login(string user, string pass, string server)` method. If you are doing additional server communication, aside from authentication, I would create yet another class for setting up and managing the connection to the remote system. Generally speaking, each class should have a fairly specific purpose and well-defined interface through which it can interact with other classes.

Google "Object Oriented Design Practices" for _much_ more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. Just to name a few, you could:

- Create a static class so all forms can access it
- Create properties on your forms and set values
- Create an event on your login form, have your other form register with the event, and pass the values back through a custom eventargs class

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a number of ways you can do that.

- `public` or `internal` properties on the forms
- events
- `public` or `internal` methods (on either form, depending on which form is sending data to which)